# Finding the volume bounded by surface $y^2=4ax$ and the planes $x+z=a$ and $z=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, multivariable-calculus, volume

The problem is stated below:

> Let $V$ be volume bounded by surface $y^2=4ax$ and the planes $x+z=a$ and $z=0$.
>
> Express $V$ as a multiple integral, whose limits should be clearly stated. Hence calculate $V$.

#### Progress

I want to find out the limits of the multiple integral that's needed to calculate $V$.

I'm guessing that:
$x=a-z$, $x=(y^2)/4a$

$$y= \pm \sqrt{4ax},\quad z=0,\quad z=a-x $$

but it seems like I've used the upper plane equation twice?

Also, it would really help if we could compare our answer volumes to check that this is right from the start!

Thanks everyone!!! :)

Comment: We don't just blindly compute homework problems here.  What's your question?

Comment: Some of us *do* "blindly" do HW problems. But it's a good idea, pikayenga, if you want folks to help out, to say "What I've done so far is XYZ, but now I don't know how to find the limits of integration", or "Should I be integrating with respect to $xy$, $xz$, or $zy$, or perhaps in some polar coordinate system? I don't know how to tell in advance what will work." Also: try to learn how to use LaTeX to write math nicely (I've done it for you on this first posting.)

Comment: So: Why not edit this posting and tell us what you've done so far?

Comment: @pikayenga is the problem finding the limits or turning the volume into an integral?

Comment: I gotta say finding those limits is not that easy at all :).

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_trough

Comment: @MickG the problem is finding the limits! I know right!! :/

Comment: @John Hughes I'm so sorry!! I didn't mean to sound like childishly ignorant...I edited my question a bit thanks for expert adivce. :) (I just signed on today...so still a bit noooby!) The problem is, I don't know how to find the limits of integration and don't have much working since I need to make sure that my starting point is correct...

Comment: @anorton sorry!!! I didn't make myself clear (it's my first post, so please forgive me) I don't know how to get the limits for the multiple integral...Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @JohnJoy oooh, you mean the surface y^2=4ax is a parabolic trough? I'm not sure how to get the limits to carry out the multiple integral. Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: You've already got the limits for $y$ (namely,  $y=\pm\sqrt{4ax}$) so ask yourself "*what is the value of $x$ when the upper plane ($z= a-x$) intersects the x-y plane (i.e. $z=0$)*?".

Comment: @JohnJoy so, you're suggesting to set x=a and x=0 as the upper and lower limits respectively for dx? Then that would leave z=a-x and z=0 as the limits for dz, right?

Comment: @pikayenga I wouldn't integrate with respect to $dz$ at all. I would integrate with respect to $dy$ and $dx$, and integrate the function $z(x,y)=a-x$

Comment: @JohnJoy If I've not misunderstood you and used the correct limits, the volume is $8(a^3)/5$ ...is that what you got as the answer to the problem?

Comment: I got a different answer. See my updated answer below.

Comment: @JohnJoy I just double checked my calculation, I made an algebraic mistake. I also got $(16/15)*a^3$ THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: yayyyy! glad to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes a picture is worth a thousand words. Eventually, a math student should try plot graphs in their minds with out the use of software (although, I've always preferred Play Doh  because after solving the problem I could always make little fishies and green froggies).

Geometrically, Your problem should look like this...
[image]

We see that $x=a$ when the upper plane intersect the $x-y$ plane. We also see that when $x=t$
$$y^2=4at$$
$$y=\pm2\sqrt{at}$$

So the integral becomes
$$\begin{array}{lll}
\int^a_0\int_{-2\sqrt{ax}}^{2\sqrt{ax}}(a-x)dydx&=&\int^a_0(a-x)(4\sqrt{ax})dx\\
&=&\int^a_0(4a^\frac{3}{2}x^\frac{1}{2} - 4a^\frac{1}{2}x^\frac{3}{2})dx\\
&=&(\frac{2}{3}\cdot 4a^\frac{3}{2}a^\frac{3}{2} - \frac{2}{5}\cdot 4a^\frac{1}{2}a^\frac{5}{2})\\
&=&8a^3(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5})\\
&=&8a^3(\frac{2}{15})\\
&=&\frac{16}{15}a^3\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very useful! :)

Comment: isn't the lower limit stated to be at z=0? How is it on the parabola?

Comment: what did you get as the volume eventually?

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: you're right, my mistake. The limits for $z$ do in fact go from $0$ to $a$.

Comment: I got the same volume as you! Woohoo! :) Thank you ever so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

OK so first of all we must turn "bounded by" into inequalities. If you picture the three surfaces, you realize the only bounded region is:

$$\left\lbrace y^2\leq 4ax,z\geq0,x+z\leq a\right\rbrace=\left\lbrace y\in[-\sqrt{4ax},\sqrt{4ax}],x,z\geq0,x\leq a-z\right\rbrace.$$

The limits for $y$ are explicit and depend on $x$, so we put the $dy$ integral inside. With that, $x,z$ don't depend on $y$, so we will have one from 0 to $a$, and the other in such a way that the sum is less than $a$. I wrote the equation in terms of $x$ to suggest my approach, but swapping the integrals shouldn't give any change.

How do we see that is the region? Well we have two planes and a 'parabolc prism'. The region outside the prism will be unbounded, which for example gives $x\geq0$ and the $y$ inequality. Under the $z=0$ plane, the region can go to infinity in $x$, since there is no upper bound for it from any of the surfaces. So $z\geq0$. The other bit, $x\leq a-z$, is just the bounding of the plane, which has to be an upper bound since the other plane is a lower one and the 'prism' doesn't touch $z$ in any way.

Hope I've been clear.

Comment: Why does the code not get rendered correctly? I only see the right half of the sets on my mobile!!

Comment: Thank you so much for helping!!! @MickG

Can I just clarify that you are suggesting the limits are:
0<x<(a-z),

-sqrt(4ax)<y<+sqrt(4ax),

0<z<a
??

Comment: I guess I'd suggest weak inequalities though @pikayenga :). Shouldn't change much anyway. _Do_ learn some LaTeX though :).

Comment: OK! I will try and learn to use LaTeX from now on! Thanks for your kind advice and help! :)

Comment: [This](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) is a good start. In particular the sections about maths. Note: this site uses MathJax, which is part of LaTeX, not the whole of LaTeX, so don't be too surprised if some commands described in the linked wikibook do not work here :). MathJax code is always between dollars `$…$` or double dollars `$$…$$` (for "displayed" equations, which are centered on a new line. You're welcome.

Comment: hahaha! aw thanks again! Yeah I was wondering why some of the symbols I was using wasn't being turned into the proper font. Turns out I was using the wrong ones and they looked even worse :P Still a noob, I guess- hopefully will get the hang of things soon!